# SQL Get id value and insert into another column

Tags: sql, insert, scope-identity

I am attempting to create an sql statement that will insert an inital record, retrieve the new id (a autonumber primary key) and insert that into another column in the table to serve as a defualt value.

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, shot, year, campus, subject,

 qual_level, job_title, blurb, presentions, offers, moderated, version_current,

 version_replace, salt, loggable) VALUES (@sfirst_name, @slast_name, @semail, @spassword,

 @sshot, @syear, @scampus, @ssubject, @squal_level, @sjob_title, @sblurb, @spresentions, 

@soffers, @smoderated, @scurrent_version, @sversion_replace, @ssalt, 1) SELECT 

SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewId UPDATE users (version_replace) VALUES (NewId) WHERE id = NewId
```

This isn't working as is and I could use a hand to correct the syntex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update isn't right it should be

```
UPDATE 
    users 
SET 
    version_replace =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()

WHERE id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

This is because this statement

`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as NewId`

Had no impact on the following statement

If you want you can also use a variable to store the NewID

```
DECLARE @NewID  int
SET @NewId =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE 
    users 
SET 
   version_replace =  @NewID  
WHERE id =@NewID
```

If you were doing this with multiple rows you would probably want to look at the [`OUTPUT` Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: I now have a error converting NewId (varchar) to int. This is strange as both are stored as int. Can you convert the datatype in an sql statement?

Comment: @Ysol8. Yes you can with `CAST` and `CONVERT` but this doesn't sound right. I'm thinking you are accidentally using the [NewID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) Function which returns a GUID

Comment: Thanks - working like a charm. I think I will have to learn complex SQL. Seems like a time saver.